# How to Write the Integral in Different Forms

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need to write the integral $\int dx\sqrt{-x^2 + 6x -5}$ in the form $\int dx\sqrt{b^2-(x-a)^2}$

I'm assuming that -1 is the a value and 6 is the b value?

Comment: $-x^2+6x-5=-\left(x^2-6x+5\right)=-\left((x-3)^2-4\right)=2^2-(x-3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

First:
$-x^2 + 6x - 5 = -(x^2 - 6x + 5)$

Complete the square:
$= -[(x^2 - 6x + 9) - 9 + 5] = -[(x - 3)^2 - 4]$

Then multiply $-1$ into the bracket:
$= 4 - (x - 3)^2 = 2^2 - (x - 3)^2$